# Bash pass variable name as argument

Tags: bash, variables, arguments

I have a simple script (let's call it script.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

source variables
echo $1
```

What I want to achieve is scripts output:

```
255.255.255.255
```

When executed like:

```
./script.sh VARIABLE
```

where VARIABLE is defined in variables file:

```
VARIABLE=255.255.255.255
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

example:

```
#!/bin/bash

variable=255.255.255.255
param=$1
echo ${!param}
```

then execute:

```
bash script.sh variable
255.255.255.255
```

The exclamation mark makes `param` to get the value of the variable with that name. See about parameter [indirection](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#indirection).

Comment: could we use `echo ${!$1}`? nop

Comment: @jon_eldiablo: `echo ${!1}` shoud do fine.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following it may help you in same.

```
./script.sh "$VARIABLE"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add $ before variable name. For example:
./script.sh $VARIABLE

Is good to put argument in double quotes like:
./script.sh „$VARIABLE”

Writing from mobile phone, sorry for no using syntax.